# SQL to Access database which allows me to select 'n' consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

This maybe a bit of a big favor to ask, but need a little help trying to get certain set of data from an access database using VB.NET. I have found a great article and the question is what I want basically, however the solutions given are unfortunately not for access.

See the thread here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/find-n-consecutive-free-numbers-from-table

The code that works for me and would be perfect is here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a2633/2

Ideally I'd have a proper SQL database but unfortunately I'm stuck with MS Access, and I know it doesn't accept `ROW_NUMBER` or `PARTITION BY` ... how do I know? I've tried and googled :~)

Basically I have a list of numbers in a database as below:

[image: Access Table]
My current SQL is

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    [ID], [UIDNo] 
FROM 
    [tblUIDS] 
WHERE 
    [Requester] IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    ID
```

The 5 is a variable where the user says i want x amount, so the SQL statement returns the top number of UIDNos, which is grand, it then does an `INSERT` statement to the requester. However id like it to be able to return 5 UIDNo that are sequential.

So based on the above image if the user wants 2 UIDNo it will return 00004 & 00005, instead of just returning 00001 & 00004. If the user wants 6 UIDNo it will return 00032-00037 etc etc.

Does using VB.NET even allow me to query a MS Access database like this? I'm open to suggestions as well if its going to be easier another way...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if there isn't enough sequencial numbers? TOP 1000000? What should be returned?

Comment: there is a limit on the variable of 3000, however if none was avaiable then return nothing. The user can always then lower their request until they do find some

Comment: I'm baffled.  Are you saying that you want to return `UIDno`s that are not in the table?  That seems strange.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Lets says thats my database as above. 
I want 3 UIDNo's. My query will return 00001,00005,00006.
However i would like it to pick out the first 3 that are sequencial which would be 00032,00033,00034.

Another scenario. I want 8 UIDNo. My query would give me 00001,00004,00005,00024,00032,00033,00034,00035. The UIDNos are not in sequence, so instead id like to get back the first 8 where they are all sequencial so it will return 00032,00033,00034,00035,00036,00037,00038,00039

Comment: @SpyingSphinx . . . I get it.  I would recommend using just about any database other than MS Access.

Comment: With Access as data source, will likely require a lot of complex code and maybe involve a 'temp' table.

Comment: This is one of the examples where simply looping the records once will be way faster and simpler than uncomprehensible SQL. _For each record_ count one up if the next UIDNo is sequential and store the ID; if not, reset the counter to one and the stored IDs and continue. When count has reached the desired number, _exit the loop_, and you have the stored IDs of the sequence. For storage, use what fits your purpose: DataTable, List, Array, Dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No temp table required.  Yes, code is pretty complex, but you can follow it.

Many thanks to the references you cited.

Currently set to get 5 records

```
SELECT TOP 5 [id],
             [uidno]
FROM   consec
WHERE  uidno >= (SELECT First(first_number) AS StartAt
                 FROM   (SELECT Min(uidno) AS first_number,
                                Count(*)   AS ct_free
                         FROM   (SELECT id,
                                        uidno,
                                        Dcount("uidno", "consec",
                                        "uidno <=" & [uidno])
                                        AS
                                        Counter,
                                        uidno - counter
                                        AS Grp
                                 FROM   (SELECT TOP 90000 [id],
                                                          [uidno]
                                         FROM   consec
                                         WHERE  [requester] IS NULL
                                         ORDER  BY uidno,
                                                   id) AS in1) x
                         GROUP  BY grp
                         HAVING Count(*) >= 5
                         ORDER  BY grp))
```

Delivers

```
id      uidno
615092  32
615093  33
615094  34
615095  35
615096  36
```